# How can I get the Schema changes between two database release‎

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, database-schema, data-dictionary

I have to note down the changes made in new database version. Those are new tables, new columns, data type changes in newer version.

We can get all tables info from `all_tables` and columns and datatype info from `all_tab_columns`. By using these data dictionary views can we get the differences made in tables.

Ex: My `Database_V1` has a `N` number of tables. In `Database_V2`, in one table I have added some new columns and for some columns i have modified datatype. I need to return these type of changes.

Is there any way? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I guess join all_objects with all_tab_columns and execute a minus expression using a DBLink to connect to the remote database dictionaries.

Comment: several tools out there let you do schema compares/diffs, including SQL Developer, which is free.